Hardware Theory: Read only Scrub of HDD/SSD drive using dd
Claim
If drives are capable of hardware controller correction of data upon read, then it is possible to routinely catch and repair silent data corruption by simply reading it.
Premises

Normally, when a drive (HDD or SSD) writes a sector, it also writes a ECC (checksum) for that sector.
If later, a bit or two bits are flipped or misread, then the hardware controller can still retrieve the correct data by comparing and correcting it with the ECC.
If the hardware controller reads a sector with bits that do not match the ECC, and the data is able to be returned read corrected, then the hardware controller may (should?) rewrite that sector data to the drive so that the bits will again match the ECC.

Do these premises appear flawed in any major way? Is there any information out there to help prove or disprove the premises in this claim?
If all of the premises here are correct, then it should be possible to help prevent silent data corruption with a simple cronjob that reads entire drives occasionally (perhaps every couple months).
dd /dev/sda > /dev/null


Usually you'd set up smartmontools to run scheduled long or select,cont self-tests. That way the drive will regularly read all of its data anyway and you should get a notification if there is any error. If you're using RAID like mdadm, there may be regular parity checks running for that as well. Checksumming filesystems similarly offer ways to check data integrity.
If none of these are available then sure, you could do it yourself with dd or ddrescue or badblocks or whatever. Whether this helps with ECC corrections and rewritings of data in the drive internally, who can say for sure? The implementation is kind of a black box. It might differ depending on make and model.
As long as you stick to read-only tests, worst case should be that nothing whatsoever happened. As such it's never wrong to test your devices.
One thing you absolutely should not do, however, is attempt to re-write the data yourself (dd if=x of=x, badblocks -n, etc.). This is where things frequently go wrong. User error, kernel or software bugs, bad ram, race conditions (if the device is otherwise in active use) etc. all come into play here.
Writing (wrong) data is exactly how "silent corruption" happens. You corrupted it yourself (or the software you used did). Can't blame the storage if its told to write garbage data.

I believe your last paragraph is mistaken, as data at rest can become corrupted due to factors like media degradation, magnetic fluctuations, radiation, temperature, or other physical issues.

Please consider removing paragraphs 1 & 4, or at least placed at the end. They are not bad advice, but they are also not strictly any necessary part of the answer. Your answer as primarily provided in paragraph 2 did not provide any external urls or information to substantiate it. I'm fairly confident that all modern ssd & hdd record ecc information specifically to correct minor discrepancies/errors in data.

You asked about using dd, I pointed out better tools and what to look out for ... how is that not a necessary part of the answer? If you're asking about hardware exclusively, it's not U&L related anymore and should probably be asked elsewhere.

I found a great answer with sources by @sawdust on Super User
https://superuser.com/questions/1583324/does-hdd-firmware-write-back-corrected-sector-when-reading-bad-but-correctable-s
In summary, the final premise looks incorrect. According to the information provided, it is unreasonable to expect a drive to correct/rewrite "recoverable errors" while reading the disk, as this would incur extra and unexpected overhead.
Instead, it is recommended to use built-in SMART tests to correct recoverable errors. Additionally, SMART tests will be more efficient as they do not have the overhead of transferring data to the host machine.
